# Installing android firmware from default recovery mode via sd card

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

I have an extra phone i.e samsung sgh i997 at home. A while back i installed **clockwork recovery** and installed cynogenmod rom on it. Then somehow out of stupidity or accident it went back into the recovery mode and everything on the phone was wiped. It even deleted clockwork recovery and i guess that even the factory firmware isn't there anymore.

Now everytime i turn on the phone, it automatically goes to the default recovery mode with 4 options

- reboot system now
- apply update from sd card
- wipe data factory reset
- wipe cache partition

I have tried switching it to **download mode** and connecting it with my laptop but the drivers are not recognized. I also tried installing kies, which i thought would help with the driver issue but it didn't. I guess there isn't any firmware inside that the driver would connect to.

Now the only way left to somehow copy something to the phone is via sd card. I tried copying several different android firmwares and mods to the sd card, but i think the default recovery mode doesn't use the external sd card but the phone's internal sd storage, which i why everybody is using clockwork recovery instead of default.

I am really tired searching for any solution to this issue, if anyone out there has done something similar or can somehow show me how to go into the shell i might be able to find my way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect it through adb then install modified 3e recovery from this [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1091465).

After it you can also install [cwm](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1107881)

But if you are unable to connect via adb then download stock signed zip of stock rom and place it in your sd card the try update from sd card.

Edit: you can try placing cwm update.zip in sd card and update from sd card. I know this can look weird but in some old Samsung mobiles I have done it because they did not check signature of zip while flashing.